# How to mark and move unread messages older than three days?

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to mark all unanswered emails, older than three days, with a flag and move them into a folder named "mini". The source is "Posteingang" (German for inbox).

```vb
Sub Mails_verschieben()
  
    Set myaccount = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").DefaultStore
    Set mynamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  
    Dim ursprung As MAPIFolder
    Dim ziel As MAPIFolder
  
    Set ursprung = Session.Folders(myaccount.DisplayName).Folders("Posteingang")
    Set ziel = Session.Folders(myaccount.DisplayName).Folders("mini")
  
    For i = ursprung.Items.Count To 1 Step -1 'alle emails im Postfach durchgehen
        With ursprung.Items(i)
            If .ReceivedTime < Date - 3 And ursprung.Items(i) = .LastModificationTime Then
                .FlagIcon = 5
                .FlagStatus = olFlagMarked
                .Save
                ursprung.Items(i).Move ziel 'in Ordner verschieben
            End If
        End With
    Next i   

End Sub
```

I get

> Object Doesn't Support this Property or Method

at

```
If .ReceivedTime < Date - 3 And ursprung.Items(i) = .LastModificationTime Then
```

I want also to run this script automatically but found nothing.

I modified my code:

```vb
Sub Mails_verschieben()

    Set myaccount = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").DefaultStore
    Set mynamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  
    Dim ursprung As MAPIFolder
    Dim ziel As MAPIFolder
    Dim MailX As MailItem
  
    Set ursprung = mynamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set ziel = Session.Folders(myaccount.DisplayName).Folders("mini")
    
    For i = ursprung.Items.Count To 1 Step -1 'alle emails im Postfach durchgehen
        For Each MailX In ursprung.Items(i)
            If MailX.ReceivedTime < Date - 3 And ursprung.Items(i) = MailX.LastModificationTime Then
                MailX.FlagIcon = 5
                MailX.FlagStatus = olFlagMarked
                MailX.Save
                ursprung.Items(i).Move ziel 'in Ordner verschieben
            End If
        Next
    Next i
End Sub
```

Also getting error.

Comment: `ursprung.Items(i)` is what your looping.  How does this compare, when you are accessing properties of it in subsequent lines, to `ursprung.Items(i) = .LastModificationTime`?  You are saying `mailitem = date` ???

Comment: can you explain it further? I am a totally beginner.

Comment: Before accessing `MailItem` specific properties you need to make sure you actually deal with a mail item. See my post for more information.

Answer (score 0):

First, please remember that an Outlook folder may contain different item types - mails, appointments, documents and etc. Check the item type at runtime to make sure you deal with mail item before accessing their properties. For example:

```
For x = 1 To Items.Count  
 If Items.Item(x).Class = OlObjectClass.olMail Then  
 ' For mail item, use the SenderName property. 
 End If
Next
```

Second, to get the standard/default Inbox folder you don't need to use the following code:

```
Set ursprung = Session.Folders(myaccount.DisplayName).Folders("Posteingang")
```

Instead, use the [NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getdefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the default folder of the requested type for the current profile.

```
Set ursprung = mynamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
```

Third, instead of iterating over all items in a folder:

```
For i = ursprung.Items.Count To 1 Step -1 'alle emails im Postfach durchgehen
    With ursprung.Items(i)
```

You need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Comment: Hi thank you for your Information.
I am a totally beginner and don't know what to do now. 
Can the loop stay as it is? I want the whole folder with all messages to be marked and only the mail types (not appointments and so on)

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be an unneeded condition in

`If MailX.ReceivedTime < Date - 3 And ursprung.Items(i) = MailX.LastModificationTime Then`

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Sub Mails_verschieben2()
    
    Dim ursprung As Folder
    Dim ziel As Folder
    
    Dim ursprungItems As Items
    Dim i As Long
    
' Not usual
    Dim myDefaultStore As Store
    Set myDefaultStore = Session.defaultStore
    
    Set ursprung = Session.Folders(myDefaultStore.DisplayName).Folders("Posteingang")
    'Set ursprung = Session.Folders(myDefaultStore.DisplayName).Folders("Inbox")
    Debug.Print ursprung.name
    
' Standard
    Set ursprung = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Debug.Print ursprung.name
    
    'Folder at same level as Inbox
    Set ziel = ursprung.Parent.Folders("mini")
    Debug.Print ziel.name
    
    Set ursprungItems = ursprung.Items
    ursprungItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True ' newest first
    
    ' You could use .Restrict but in normal sized inboxes
    '  the time saved may not be noticeable.
    For i = ursprungItems.count To 1 Step -1 'alle emails im Postfach durchgehen
        
        ' Verify that the item is a mailitem
        '  before attempting to return mailitem properties
        If TypeOf ursprungItems(i) Is mailItem Then
                            
            With ursprungItems(i)
            
                If .ReceivedTime < Date - 3 Then
                    '.FlagIcon = 5
                    '.FlagStatus = olFlagMarked
                    '.Save
                    '.Move ziel 'in Ordner verschieben
                    
                    Debug.Print "Older mail."
                    Debug.Print " Subject: " & .Subject
                    Debug.Print "  ReceivedTime: " & .ReceivedTime
                    
                Else
                    Debug.Print "Newer mail."
                    Debug.Print " Subject: " & .Subject
                    Debug.Print "  ReceivedTime: " & .ReceivedTime
                    
                    Exit For    ' Stop when newer mail encountered.
                    
                End If
                
            End With
            
        Else
        
            Debug.Print "Non-mailitem ignored."
            
        End If
        
    Next i
    
    Debug.Print "Done."
    
End Sub
```